# Asp.Net, VB, SQL Server Reporting Services..dynamically generated reports from directory to be viewed on report viewer on click?

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, reporting-services

I have an aspx webform that in it's vb code reads files that are .rdl from a directory and then lists them as say a button or hyper link etc. "reports are on local host report server"

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
Dim FileLocation As DirectoryInfo = _
New DirectoryInfo("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Reports")

Dim fi As FileInfo() = FileLocation.GetFiles("*.rdl")

For Each name As FileInfo In fi
    ' Dim i As Integer
    Dim listed As New LinkButton
    ' listed.Attributes("CssClass") = "a"
    ' listed.Attributes("Class") = "a"
    listed.Attributes("id") = "listed"
    listed.Text = (name.Name)

    mine.Controls.Add(listed)
    'mine.InnerHtml = ""
    'i = i + 1
Next
End Sub
```

and another that has a reportviewer. When a report was clicked, how can I send the name/value to the viewer and redirect to it?

Thank you very much

EDIT: i got to make the click redirect to the viewer with a string and have the viewer use that string,but with how much ever variation ive tried it still errors that

> The path of the item 'salesreport.rdl' is not valid. The full path must be less than 260 characters long; other restrictions apply. If the report server is in native mode, the path must start with slash. (rsInvalidItemPath)

this is the viewer code

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        ' Retrieve parameter from Route "Reports/{reportName}"
        Dim reportName = Picks.Selecty

        'Page.Title = reportName

        ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote
        Dim serverReport As ServerReport
        ServerReport = ReportViewer1.ServerReport
        serverReport.ReportServerUrl = New Uri("http://localhost/reportserver/")
        serverReport.ReportPath = reportName
        ' reportName
        ' 
        ' add parameters here
        'Dim param As New ReportParameter("name", "value")
        'serverReport.SetParameters(param)

        serverReport.Refresh()

    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following.

1. Create a new page say ReportViewer.aspx which hosts your ReportViewer Control that recieves the name of the .RDL file as a query string.
2. In the First .aspx page, for every link you display, point the NavigateURL property to ReportViewer.aspx page and pass the name of the .RDL file as a QueryString.

Hope that helps

Thanks,
Prawin

Comment: thank you very much for answering,Prawin..i was not quite sure what you meant but i tried as i understood,by when clicking on the link it stores the name displayed to a string and send it to the page with the viewer,but i was stumbed there,any further help? much appreciated,friend

Comment: forgot to mention you @Prawin